# How to create group boxes in a QGIS custom form using Qt Designer?

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I am trying to create a custom form for QGIS using Qt Designer.

Let's say I have a field which uses relational values. I want these values to be checkboxes. I can do it easily with the included form designer in QGIS.

Now I am trying to get this with Qt Designer using checkboxes grouped together in a GroupBox widget. But I can't manage to get the values back to QGIS.

[image: Form designer in QGIS]
The form designer in QGIS.

[image]
The custom form made from the form designer using relational values.

[image]
The custom form I would like to create in Qt Designer.

Comment: I asked this question years ago and never had an answer, and spent another couple of hours today trying to solve exactly the same problem, without any success. There's a widget on QT Designer named QgsCheckableComboBox which looked like it might work, but I can't set up any combination of settings to make it record what's input into the check boxes. Would love to hear an answer to this - or even simply to know for certain that there isn't an easy one.,